# AppBarLayout cannot show after click onBackPressed Button

Tags: android, kotlin, android-appbarlayout

I want to show AppBarLayout when users click `onBackPressed` button. How can I do that?
this is my code

fragment DetailPost

```
private fun toolBarListener(view: View){
    val toolbar: Toolbar = view.findViewById(R.id.tbDetailPost) as Toolbar

    toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener {

        if (context is GeneralActivity){
            (context as GeneralActivity).setAppBarVisible()
        }else if(context is ProfileActivity){
            (context as ProfileActivity).setAppBarVisible()
        }else if (context is NotificationActivity){
            (context as NotificationActivity).setAppBarVisible()
        }
        activity?.onBackPressed()
    }
}
```

this is function setAppBarVisible()

```
fun setAppBarVisible() {
    appBarLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Override `onBackPressed()` method and then call `setAppBarVisible()` like:

```
override fun onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed()
    setAppBarVisible()
}
```